# Xcode Localization failed with xib files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I was working through iOS programming 3rd edition by Joe Conway and am stuck on localization. I added two languages under project - info, then clicked the localize button on the .xib file, finally translated the other .xib into the new language and checked that they are in the right folders. However no matter how many times I try the .xib refuse to display in the new language when I change language in simulator settings.

In addition, when I checked the current language with NSLog and NSLocale it tells me I am in the right language. I can even use this to translate by code some of the table cell contents I was displaying. But the correct .xib file just won't load.

Any help?

Comment: Try to clean the project, delete the app in the simulator and re-run the app.

Comment: Nope doesn't work :/ I've cleaned it quite many times...

Comment: Have you deleted the app or reset the simulator?